# Querying multiple tables at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have many tables with different structure that have a common column. How can I query for all rows from all these tables based on a condition.

Example:

```
table1:
column1 | column2 | user_id

table2:
columna | columnb | columnc | user_id

...
```

The condition would be `user_id = <some number>`. I don't want to query each table individually as there are about 30 tables. There may not be a record for each `user_id` in each table. What's the best option to do this?

Comment: Do you have a business case? and what do you mean by many tables? of course there will be some logical definite linking between them, otherwise Database itself will be a crap.

Comment: This often suggests design issues. Can you explain *why* you need to do this?

Comment: This was just a contrived example. I wasn't seeking design advice. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for a `full outer join`

```
select * 
from (
  select *
  from table1 t1 
    full outer join table2 t2 using (user_id)
    full outer join table3 t2 using (user_id)
) t
where user_id = 42;
```

The `using (user_id)` syntax will make sure that the common column `user_id` is only present once in the result. So even though the query uses `select *`, there will only be a single `user_id` column in the result on which you can apply the `where` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the Tables on the user_id.
Inner JOIN would be good. 
You have to set primarykeys and foreignkeys

Comment: See my first comment for @Rahul's answer. A simple outer or inner join won't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship or a common column between the tables; like in your posted case `user_id` you can perform a simple `JOIN` like

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where user_id = <some number>;
```

But if there is no relation exists (or) you can't join them then there is no other way than querying them individually.

Comment: That won't work as this requires a row to exist in t1 and t2 for a result to be returned. If either of the tables does not have a row with the condition being true, nothing will be returned. An outer join doesn't work either it requires the left (or right) row to exist.

Comment: @orange, read the answer carefully. That's what I said ... in that case no other way than query individually.

Comment: That's not how I understood it, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, the user table would be a good way to combine these and joining the others. (`select t1.*, t2.* from user left outer join table t1 join on ... left outer join table t1 ...`).

Comment: @orange, that I can't comment about since I have no idea about your table structures but as long there is a common column join would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this very case outer join would server the purpose instead of inner Join as there may not be a record for each user_id in each table.

On other note I strongly feel that joining multiple tables(specially 30) would navigate to "locking" of tables for longer period of time and that can hamper your DB as well as your application. Restructuring of DB can be an option but in case you can't change it,make cluster of similar data which can have 4-5 table dat at once,mean total 6-7 queries, use multithreading from application end as each thread would snatch data for its respective query, club them together to create set of required information. This will enhance your application performance.

Comment: Joining tables does most definitely _not_ "lock" them - not in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Here are  some articles. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html          and         https://www.compose.io/articles/common-misconceptions-about-locking-in-postgresql/

Comment: You misunderstand that page. The tables are not "locked". Postgres puts a specific lock on the table, but that does not mean the table cannot be "accessed". Most of the locks that are listed there can be hold by different transactions at the same time. You need to carefully read the "Conflicts with" part in the description of each lock.